# WebGL2: Drawing a textured quad causes artifacts at boundary when using mip-mapping

Tags: webgl, textures, texture-mapping

I'm drawing a quad with texture coordinates ranging from 0-1 onto a canvas using WebGL2. This quad is used to draw an image to the canvas which can be zoomed and moved by the user. I use nearest-filtering on the texture in order to see sharp pixels. When no mip-mapping is enabled everything works as expected, but as soon as I turn on mip-mapping I get artifacts at the boundary (even when zoomed in a lot in which case only the most detailed mip-map should be at work). These artifacts are usually only a single pixel wide, no matter how to much I zoom in.

Here's an example (the white line on the right of the quad):
[image]

Somebody knows what's causing this and how to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 0):

The mip level is derived by the *screen-space* derivative of the given coordinates, so the more the coordinates change from one pixel to another the higher the miplevel(=lower-res mipmap) that is being sampled from. Now when you shade a fragment that is on the edge of the surface so that the edge runs through the pixel and you have your texture wrapping set to `REPEAT` there's a good chance the derivative will be huge which will result in a lower resolution mipmap being sampled from:

[image: UV derivative over pixel footprint]

The fix is easy, don't use `REPEAT`.

```js
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
const 
  vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER),
  fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER),
  program = gl.createProgram(),
  texture = gl.createTexture()
;
gl.shaderSource(vs, `#version 300 es
uniform vec3 transform;
out vec2 uv;
void main(){
  gl_Position = vec4(gl_VertexID<2,gl_VertexID%2,.5,1)*2.-1.;
  uv = gl_Position.xy*.5+.5;
  gl_Position.xy+=transform.xy;
  gl_Position.xy*=transform.z;
}`);
gl.shaderSource(fs, `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D tex;
in vec2 uv;
out vec4 OUT;
void main(){
  OUT=texture(tex,uv);
}`);
gl.compileShader(vs);gl.attachShader(program, vs);
gl.compileShader(fs);gl.attachShader(program, fs);
gl.linkProgram(program);
const log = gl.getProgramInfoLog(program);
if (log) console.warn(log);
gl.useProgram(program);

const transformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'transform');
const fixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'fix');
gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'tex'),0);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 2, 2, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([
  255,0,0,255, 255,255,0,255,
  0,255,0,255, 0,0,255,255
]));
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT);
gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);

let drag=false,x=.54321,y=-.54321,z=1;
canvas.addEventListener('pointerdown',()=>drag=true);
canvas.addEventListener('pointerup',()=>drag=false);
canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', (e)=>{
  if(!drag)return;
  x+=e.movementX*.001;
  y-=e.movementY*.001;
});
canvas.addEventListener('wheel', (e)=>z=Math.min(Math.max(z+e.deltaY*.01,.3),5.));

filter.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
const val = parseInt(filter.value,10);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, val);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, val);
});

(function render(){
gl.uniform3f(transformLocation,x,y,z);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
requestAnimationFrame(render);
})();
```

```css
canvas{outline: 1px solid red;}
label{display:block;}
```

```html
<label>Filter<select id="filter"><option value="10497">REPEAT</option><option value="33071">CLAMP_TO_EDGE</option><option value="33648">MIRRORED_REPEAT</option></select></label><canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

This is how it looks for me, you can see the red/blue mipmap fringing around the green square.
[image: Mipmap fringing]

Comment: actually I'm using CLAMP_TO_EDGE

Comment: also if the explanation you gave is correct this seems like a pretty bad bug in the GL implementation as the pixel pitch should be computed w.r.t. the wrapping mode when determining the mip-map level (otherwise tiled textures would never work with mip-mapping).

Comment: Changing the wrapping mode fixes the issue for me (check the added code snippet), afaik it only happens on the edge of polygons (the orange surface was meant to represent the polygon) when one of the fragments that's used for the derivative is outside the geometry, what I'm referring to is explained in more detail [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/new-trouble-with-screen-space-partial-derivatives-and-tex2dgrad.853279/#post-5626756) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130888/what-are-screen-space-derivatives-and-when-would-i-use-them).

Comment: hmm, yeah. i can see it in your demo and i get the same effect (seeing the problem with REPEAT which is really very similar if not the same to what i see in my case and it vanishes when using CLAMP_TO_EDGE). now i'm really puzzled why the problem persists in my case even though i do use CLAMP_TO_EDGE.

Comment: Using a TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY with a single layer should not change any of the described behaviour, right ?